# I need to find a way to delete everything after the third .bak file in a SQL Server backup folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, shell, powershell

Working on an old SQL Server cluster that has a limited amount of space available. The cluster uses a SAS (server 2003 database) for data backups: `fc_mdt`, `fc_mdt_trend`, `fc_adt`. Inside those folders are multiple `.bak` and `.trn` files.

I'm looking for a way to automate deletion of everything after the third `.bak` file when the folder contents are listed by date modified

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with using powershell, then this script will help you

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\YourDirectory" | where{$_.Extension -eq ".bak"} |
sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending| Select -Skip 3 | Remove-Item -Include .bak
```

Comment: Always have the Provider (in this case the file system provider) filter, it's faster... `Get-ChildItem "C:\YourDirectory\*.bak" | Sort .....`

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing automated backups using a maintenance plan why not configure it to remove files older than a specific age, for example:

[image]